# Getting error in android support library

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I'm facing this issue since 2 days. my build tool version is 25.0.2.
sdk version is 25.
i'm getting error in one line. please tell me how to solve it. thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should downgrade `firebase-core` and `firebase-messaging` to 11.0.4 (It is requires `com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0`)

Current `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2` requires `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2`, which requires `com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0` (and it is for compileSdk 26)

Quote from release notes:

> When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or
>   later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a
>   compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O).